# What is the type of angular 2 components if they are decorated?

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I need to have a map of different angular components. This is the map:

```
  private modals: MapOf<any> = {
    addAttribute: AddAttributeModalComponent,
    editAttribute: EditAttributeModalComponent,
    requestUnit: RequestUnitModalComponent,
    requestAttribute: RequestAttributeModalComponent
  };
```

As you can see, I have a generic type MapOf. This is it:

```
export interface MapOf<T> {
  [key: string]: T;
}
```

Right now I am confused with < any >, because clearly this is a map of components. But I don't know how to set this type and I couldn't find the answer.

ComponentRef doesn't fit here, because it asks for a reference anyway.
Type Component doesn't fit also, because my components are decorated and they contain some methods which are not present on 'pure' Component.

Any ideas?

Comment: so you would want to be able to write something like `new modals.addAttribute().addAtributeMethod()` ?

Comment: No, not at all. I would like to set the type for my components.

Comment: I need something like type: AngularComponent

Comment: What do you want to be able to *do* with something you get out of that map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decorators don't change the type of the class. If you just want to avoid using the type `any`, have each component class to extend the same abstract class or implement the same interface. Then you can use this new type as the generic one. For example,

```
class AddAttributeModalComponent implements MyInterface{...}

MapOf<MyInterface> = {...}
```

The other option to try would be to create a new union type:

```
type MyNewType = AddAttributeModalComponent | 
                 EditAttributeModalComponent |
                 RequestUnitModalComponent |
                 RequestAttributeModalComponent;

MapOf<MyNewType> = {...};
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer: There're no such thing like that.**

**Long Answer:** We define the `Component` by using the `@Component({...})` decorator to provide some metadata about the `Component`. Angular will use that metadata to create the `View`, which is a low-level abstraction of the `Component` we used to know.

So, the below `Component` interface for the `@Component` decorator is NOT the real "component class":

`import {Component} from '@angular/core';`

To achieve what you're trying to do, I think [Yakov Fain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51171352/1589218) is quite correct. Either you can create an interface or an abstract class then implement/extend your component classes from there.

If you want to know more about the view, there're some nice articles by Ng Wizard about this topic:

- https://indepth.dev/posts/1052/exploring-angular-dom-manipulation-techniques-using-viewcontainerref
- https://indepth.dev/posts/1053/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular